# Sequelize foreign key of uuid gives error 1215

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

given the following migration snippet:

```
const uuid = require('uuid');
queryInterface.createTable('listings', {
        id: {
          type: Sequelize.UUID,
          defaultValue: () => uuid.v4(),
          primaryKey: true,
          allowNull: false,
          isUnique: true,
        },
});
```

and another one:

```
queryInterface.createTable('listing_detail_info', {
        id: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
          primaryKey: true,
          autoIncrement: true,
          allowNull: false,
          isUnique: true,
        },
        listingId: {
          type: Sequelize.UUID,
          isUnique: true,
          allowNull: false,
          field: 'listing_id',
          references: { model: 'listings', key: 'id' },
        },
});
```

the following error happened:

```
 code: 'ER_CANNOT_ADD_FOREIGN',
     errno: 1215,
     sqlState: 'HY000',
     sqlMessage: 'Cannot add foreign key constraint',
     sql:
      'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `listing_detail_info` (`id` INTEGER(11) NOT NULL auto_increment , `listing_id` CHAR(36) BINARY NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), FOREIGN KEY (`listing_id`) REFERENCES `listings` (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;' },
```

I am pretty sure they are the same data type (both Sequleize.UUID), and the previous table has been successfully created, but no idea why this still happens...

Answer (score 1):

just try this

```
queryInterface.createTable('listing_detail_info', {
        id: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
          primaryKey: true,
          autoIncrement: true,
          allowNull: false,
          isUnique: true,
        },
        listingId: {
          type: Sequelize.UUID,
          isUnique: true,
          allowNull: false,
        },
});
```

if given solution work then there is problem to add foreign key constraint.

Comment: It's not a surprise that the problem is to add foreign key constraint - the error message already said so...

Answer (score 0):

This codes below works for me. Btw this is what I'm using

- "express": "^4.18.1"
- "sequelize": "^6.21.3"
- "mysql2": "^2.3.3",

for listings i just change defaultValue to Sequelize.UUIDV4

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('listings', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false,
        isUnique: true,
      },
    });
  },
  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('listings');
  }
};
```

for this part is same

```
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.createTable('listing_detail_info', {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        isUnique: true,
      },
      listingId: {
        type: Sequelize.UUID,
        isUnique: true,
        allowNull: false,
        field: 'listing_id',
        references: { model: 'listings', key: 'id' },
      },
    });
  },

  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('listing_detail_info');
  }
};
```